# how to add data in href with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have a code to get all the 5 links from the site, so I need to change these links by putting "https://advancecare.pt" before......

For now I have this code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("myLink");

  foreach (HtmlNode ic in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='component row-splitter']"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {

                    HtmlNode test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").First();
                    string hrefValue =  link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                   // test.SetAttributeValue("href", "mylink" + hrefValue);
                    
                    link.SetAttributeValue("href", "mylink" + hrefValue);
                    
                }

            }
```

This code return:

https:mylinkmylinkmylinkmylink/hrefValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate all **div** nodes in the document, and then iterate all links within document, so each link is being processed as many times as **div** elements in the document.

Seach only links which are children for div:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in ic.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
...
```